# Use Duhamel's principle in PDE

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, differential

Let $u(t,x)$ be solution for:

$$ u_{tt}-u_{xx}=q(t,x)u$$

with zero initial conditions. If $q$ is bounded in $\mathbb{R}^2$, show that $u \equiv 0$ using [Duhamel's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duhamel%27s_principle)

Comment: What are your thoughts? Where are you stuck? You need to provide context for your question. Right now, it just looks like you want somebody to do your homework for you; that's not what this site is for. If you add some appropriate context, people will be happy to help.

Comment: Glad you want to help. I do not want my homework to be resolved, I do not have homework. This is something that appears in a book and I would like to see someone solving it in a different way, but finally I did it myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Duhamel's principle, we must:

$$ u_{tt}-u_{xx}=q(t,x)u \Rightarrow u(t,x) = \iint\limits_{\triangle (t,x)} {q(s,y)} {u(s,y)} ds dy $$

Let $M = \sup\limits_{\triangle (t,x)}|{u(t,x)}|$ be note that the sup is assumed in the triangle. Consider $(t_1,x_1) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $M=|u(t_1,x_1)|$ then

$$M=|u(t_1,x_1)|=|\iint\limits_{\triangle} {q(s,y)} {u(s,y)} ds dy| \leq \iint\limits_{\triangle} |{q(s,y)}| |{u(s,y)}| ds dy \leq M\iint\limits_{\triangle} |{q(s,y)}| ds dy$$

as the function q is limited $\exists K \in \mathbb{R}$ such that$\iint\limits_{\triangle} |{q(s,y)}| ds dy \leq K \iint\limits_{\triangle} ds dy$.
It is easy to see that there is a T such that the area of ​​the triangle is less than $1 \over2$.

$$M \leq \iint\limits_{\triangle } M |{q(s,y)}|  ds dy  \leq M K \iint\limits_{\triangle} ds dy = MK A(\triangle) < \frac{1}{2}M $$

So we conclude that $M = 0$ and therefore $u(t,x) \equiv 0$.